Python unittest mocking influxdb failed
I'm writing a code on Python to test by connecting the influxDB with a mock.
However, an IndexError occurs while sending a query.
I tried changing the data frame to the same form as the real thing, but the same error still occurs.
How can I solve this problem?
This is the class I want to test:
class DataManager:

    def __init__(self, db_url, token, org, bucket):
        self.client = InfluxDBClient(url=db_url, token=token, org=org, timeout=30_000)
        self.bucket = bucket

    def query_influx(self, measurement, place):
        query_api = self.client.query_api()

        query = f'''
        import "date"
        import "experimental/query"
        from(bucket: "{self.bucket}")
        |> range(start: date.sub(d: 7d, from: date.truncate(t: now(), unit: 1d)), stop: now())
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "{measurement}")
        |> pivot(rowKey:["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r.place == "{place}")
        '''
        result_df = query_api.query_data_frame(query=query)
        print(f"{place} {measurement} shape: ", result_df.shape)
        return result_df

This is the test case
from unittest import TestCase
import pandas as pd
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch, MagicMock
from model_manager import ModelManager
from data_manager import DataManager

class TestDataManager(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.db_url = "http://test-url.com"
        self.token = "test-token"
        self.org = "test-org"
        self.bucket = "TxT-iot"
        self.data_manager = DataManager(self.db_url, self.token, self.org, self.bucket)


    @patch('data_manager.InfluxDBClient')
    def test_query_influx(self, mock_client):

        mock_query_api = Mock()
        mock_client.return_value.query_api.return_value = mock_query_api

        df_test = pd.DataFrame({
            'test_column': [1, 2, 3],
            'test_column2': [1, 2, 3],
        })
        mock_query_api.query_data_frame.return_value = df_test

        df = self.data_manager.query_influx('temperature', 'class_a')
        mock_query_api.query_data_frame.assert_called_once()
        self.assertEqual(df.shape, df_test.shape)

When running the test code, the following error occurs.
ERROR: test_query_influx (test_data_manager.TestDataManager)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py", line 1336, in patched
    return func(*newargs, **newkeywargs)
  File "/home/Final_Project/txt/TxT-AI-learning/test_data_manager.py", line 38, in test_query_influx
    df = self.data_manager.query_influx('temperature', 'class_a')
  File "/home/Final_Project/txt/TxT-AI-learning/data_manager.py", line 44, in query_influx
    result_df = query_api.query_data_frame(query=query)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/influxdb_client/client/query_api.py", line 261, in query_data_frame
    return self._to_data_frames(_generator)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/influxdb_client/client/_base.py", line 324, in _to_data_frames
    _dataFrames = list(_generator)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/influxdb_client/client/flux_csv_parser.py", line 117, in generator
    for val in parser._parse_flux_response():
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/influxdb_client/client/flux_csv_parser.py", line 128, in _parse_flux_response
    for val in self._parse_flux_response_row(metadata, csv):
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/influxdb_client/client/flux_csv_parser.py", line 158, in _parse_flux_response_row
    elif "error" == csv[1] and "reference" == csv[2]:
IndexError: list index out of range
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 1.851s

FAILED (errors=1)

I tried to test whether the connection to influxDB was good and an appropriate response was received, but fail continued to occur.
